# Unique lists in nested list in numba

Tags: list, tuples, numba

I would like to find the number of unique lists within a nested list in a nopython numba function, e.g:

```
from collections import Counter

def number_of_unique_lists_v1(a):
    uniques = Counter(tuple(item) for item in a)
    number = len(uniques.keys())
    return number

print(number_of_unique_lists_v1([[1,2,3],[1,2],[3,4],[1,2,3])
>>> 3
```

or

```
def number_of_unique_lists_v2(a):
    uniques = [list(x) for x in set(tuple(x) for x in a)]
    number = len(uniques)
    return number

print(number_of_unique_lists_v2([[1,2,3],[1,2],[3,4],[1,2,3])
>>> 3
```

Unfortunately, both ideas don't work with @nb.njit. How can I make it work?

***Edit***:

Using the approach of mpw2 I found that in principle the following code works:

```
from numba.typed import List
@nb.njit
def number_of_unique_lists_v3():
    a = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2, 3]]
    s = List()
    for x in a:
        if not x in s:
            s.append(x)
    number = len(s)
    return number


print(number_of_unique_lists())
>>> 3
```

BUT this does not work for me since the list `a`  is created slightly differently in my function, similar as shown in a minimal example below.

```
from numba.typed import List
@nb.njit
def number_of_unique_lists():
    a = [[0] for _ in range(4)]
    a[0] = [1, 2, 3]
    a[1] = [1, 2]
    a[2] = [3, 4]
    a[3] = [1, 2, 3]
    s = List()
    for x in a:
        if not x in s:
            s.append(x)
    number = len(s)
    return number
```

Now I get an error which I don't understand...

Answer (score 1):

Here is one working solution using numba.typed.List() objects

```
import numba as nb
from numba.typed import List

@nb.njit
def number_of_unique_lists(a):
    s = List()
    for x in a:
        if not x in s:
            s.append(x)
    number = len(s)
    return number

a = [[1,2,3],[1,2],[3,4],[1,2,3]]
typed_a = List()
for x in a:
    s = List()
    for y in x:
        s.append(y)
    typed_a.append(s)
print(number_of_unique_lists(typed_a))
>>> 3
```

Comment: Do I have to create the typed_a list outside of the numba function? Unfortunately that is not possible. The numba function contains a loop that constantly changes the list a.

Comment: Please see my Edit